# how to add box shadow to half of its height

Tags: css, box-shadow

I am trying add shadow to a div. shadow should be at top and half of its height from top ( to both left and right side), someone please help me.

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a demonstration of what you'd like to achieve. Also, are you aware that your CSS selector (i.e. `.test`) will not target an element with an **ID** of `test`.

Comment: http://cssreference.io/#box-shadow

Answer (score 11):

you can increase offset and reduce size of box shadow and draw 2 of them.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow
>
> /* offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
>
> `<spread-radius>`
>
> This is a fourth  value. Positive values will cause the shadow to expand and grow bigger, negative values will cause the shadow to shrink. If not specified, it will be 0 (the shadow will be the same size as the element).

```css
#test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: -50px -50px 5px -50px, 50px -50px 5px -50px
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be a simple way to do it, quite a few possibilities.

```css
.parent{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.test {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px red;
  background-color: white;
}

.halfshadow{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  height: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="halfshadow"></div>
</div>
```